# How to use regex and match data using find/aggregate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a phone number like +1234567890. In database the phone number is stored as +123-456-789 or +123-(456)-(789). How can I match my phone number +1234567890 with +123-456-789 or +123-(456)-(789) using the MongoDB query.

like {removeSpecialCharacters(phoneno):1234567890}

Comment: nope, I want to find in my DB collection

Comment: +123-456-789 or +123-(456)-(789) Are these the only two cases, or there can be more?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with because I saw you have tagged "javascript" in this question as well.

It is not a single aggregate query but instead, I am iterating over each entry using a forEach loop in a mongo script( Javascript file which can be executed with mongo).

**DataSet**

```
{"name": "SV", phone:"+1234567890"},
{"name": "MV", phone:"+123-(456)-(789)"}
```

**Logic**

```
var entries = [];
var phone_number_to_be_searched = "+1234567890";
phone_number_to_be_searched = phone_number_to_be_searched.replace(/\D/g,''); 

db.temp.find().forEach(function(entry) {
    var phone = entry["phone"].replace(/\D/g,'');
    if(phone === phone_number_to_be_searched){
        entries.push(entry)
    }
})
print(JSON.stringify(entries));
```

**Output**

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5d6cf41ce920d9c4fa760121"},"name":"SV","phone":"+1234567890"}]
```

As you can see, we have only one entry in output having phone number "1234567890", as the other entry is missing a "0".

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate that It would be helpful if I found the solution of finding directly from the collection without fetching all data and filtering it.